# How to Change the current working Directory in Git?

Tags: git, directory, branch, clone

When I am adding a new project to repository, I am getting this error.

```
Error - fatal: '/Users/username/Downloads/folder_name' is outside repository.
```

I think, I need to give the current working directory. But, don't know how to do that..Can anyone help me out of this? But when I add new file directly, it works fine.. Your help is highly appreciated..Thanks in advance.

I got everything fine..But if I refresh the page, it remains the same...
https://github.com/dinesh-prodapt/myandroid.git

That's why confused.. Here is what I am getting..

```
Dinesh-iMac:~ dineshkumar$ git remote add origin git@github.com:dinesh-prodapt/myandroid.git
    fatal: remote origin already exists.
    Dinesh-iMac:~ dineshkumar$ git push -u origin master
    Counting objects: 3, done.
    Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
    Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
    Writing objects: 100% (2/2), 280 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
    Total 2 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
    To git@github.com:dinesh-prodapt/dinesh.git
       c6537f0..433adae  master -> master
    Branch master set up to track remote branch master from origin.
    Dinesh-iMac:~ dineshkumar$ git remote add origin git@github.com:dinesh-prodapt/myandroid.git
    fatal: remote origin already exists.
    Dinesh-iMac:~ dineshkumar$ git push -u origin master
    Branch master set up to track remote branch master from origin.
    Everything up-to-date
```

Comment: "When I am adding a new project to git" - why don't use create a separate repo for that project? Why do you want to have multiple projects in the same repo?

Comment: what command created that error message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you cant add a file to git using `git add` that it outside of the folder.

for example

```
/Users/username/dir1
```

Contains the .git folder (ie the git root)

you can only add folders and files below that

such as

```
/Users/username/dir1/images
/Users/username/dir1/src
/Users/username/dir1/dir2
```

But not

```
/Users/username/dir2
/Users/username/Desktop
```

because they are outside of what git knows about

you need to move the file (or copy) with the mv or cp commands to dir1 and then use `git add`

to the second problem (which you should really create a new question for)

git remote origin exists already so call it something else or remove your exiting origin

```
git remote add github git@github.com:dinesh-prodapt/myandroid.git
git push -u github master
```

Comment: even though I tried to copy and paste the folder in git directory and tried this command.... git add /Users/dineshkumar/License  but didnt work

Comment: you need to use `cp` not  `git add` cp will copy it there, `git add` will add the file to staging

Comment: I created repository in remote git and I need to upload the folder there...how to do that?

Comment: use `cp` to move it into the git folder, then `git add file` `git commit` `git push`

Comment: I have edited my question. Kindly look into that and pls reply your answer